# PostgreSQL aggregate views

Tags: sql, postgresql

Are views in PostgreSQL completely recalculated every time one of underneath tables are changed?

More precisely, if I have aggregate view over table `votes`, will complete recalculation of a view be needed, when any changes are made in votes table?

If I expect often changes of `votes` table, what are alternatives to aggregate view? I need polylogarithmic time complexity of simple querys.

Comment: I dunno about PostgreSQL particularly, but SQL Server & Oracle capture the table(s) at the time the CREATE VIEW statement is executed, so yes - if the VOTES table changes then you need to refresh the view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal VIEWS in Postgres (and other RDBMS's that I'm aware of) are really nothing more than a stored SELECT statement. Its not storing the actual information in a static table - thats a materialized VIEW (which Postgres doesn't currently have, and you'll have to [roll your own](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views)).  It will in a sense "recalculate every time", in that it doesn't store the calculated data.

Check the [previous link](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views) for how to do a materialized view if you want to store the complex calculations.

EDIT: If like OMG Ponies says, you're talking about ALTER TABLE on the underlying table - then its easy...Postgres won't let you change the definition of a column that used in a VIEW without dropping the VIEW first.

Comment: +1: I agree that views are stored SELECTs, but the OP is asking about if they run an ALTER TABLE statement to add/edit a column - will the PostgreSQL view stay in sync?  Assume `SELECT *...` - least, that's why I read the question.

Comment: I didn't think he was talking about ALTER TABLE, I thought it was just talking about changing the data in the table.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about changing the data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PostgreSQL's Materialized views.

Materialized views are certainly possible in PostgreSQL. Because of PostgreSQL's powerful PL/pgSQL language, and the functional trigger system, materialized views are somewhat easy to implement. I will examine several methods of implementing materialized views in PostgreSQL.

[link text](http://tech.jonathangardner.net/wiki/PostgreSQL/Materialized_Views)

Comment: Postgres doesn't have native Materialized View syntax, and this doesn't address the OP's question either...